# How to represent an attribute of type Optional <T> on OpenAPI 3

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am writing an OpenAPI 3 spec for a Servlet.

Here is the piece of code:

```
    Protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Dao dao = new Dao();
        Optional<String> requestBody = request.getReader() //*** Question: we retreive the informationJson from idJson?    is it a body parameter ?
                .lines()
                .reduce((identity, accumulator) -> identity + " " + accumulator);
        String informationIdJson = null;

        if (requestBody.isPresent())
            informationIdJson = requestBody.get()
                           ...
}
```

I tried defining this request object in a definition as shown below:

```
                    ...
 /ServletName: #OK
    post:
      tags:
      - ServletName
      requestBody:
          description: Optional description in *Markdown*
          required: true
                   ...
```

Knowing that requestBody can contain a String value or an empty value (not-null).

Is this correct what I did?